# C char input not working as expected with switch and for loop

Tags: c, input

Attempting to make a menu for a 2048 clone in C, taking a character input, and using a switch to determine the action to take.

Expected behaviour example:

Input: `'P'`
Output: `"Playing the game"` (then loop back to start)

Actual:
`"Playing the gameError, please enter valid input (P/S/Q)"`

When multiple characters entered, it appears to loop through all in the switch before printing invalid input.

Code: (also [here](https://repl.it/@trotemus/C-char-input-issue#main.c))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header2048.h"

int main(){
    unsigned char useroption;

    printf(" .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. \n");
    printf("| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |\n");
    printf("| |    _____     | || |     ____     | || |   _    _     | || |     ____     | |\n");
    printf("| |   / ___ `.   | || |   .'    '.   | || |  | |  | |    | || |   .' __ '.   | |\n");
    printf("| |  |_/___) |   | || |  |  .--.  |  | || |  | |__| |_   | || |   | (__) |   | |\n");
    printf("| |   .'____.'   | || |  | |    | |  | || |  |____   _|  | || |   .`____'.   | |\n");
    printf("| |  / /____     | || |  |  `--'  |  | || |      _| |_   | || |  | (____) |  | |\n");
    printf("| |  |_______|   | || |   '.____.'   | || |     |_____|  | || |  `.______.'  | |\n");
    printf("| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |\n");
    printf("| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |\n");
    printf(" '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------' \n");

    printf("\nPLEASE CHOOSE AN OPTION:\n");
    printf("(P) - PLAY\n(S) - SCORES\n(Q) - QUIT\nSELECT OPTION:   ");
    
    for(;;){
        useroption = getchar();

        switch(useroption){
            case 'P' :
                PlayGame();
                break;
            case 'S' :
                DisplayScores();
                break;
            case 'Q' :
                exit(0);
            case '\0' :
                printf("NULL character");
                break;
            default :
                printf("Error, please enter valid input (P/S/Q)");
        }

    }
}

void PlayGame(void){
    printf("Playing the game");
}

void DisplayScores(void){
    printf("Displaying Scores");
}
```

Cannot understand why this won't work honestly (new to C), pretty much stuck (hence this post).

Comment: Your input was actually 'P' 'Enter'

Comment: your program did what you told it to do. It went round the loop again and the switch couldn't recognize the 'enter' keypress

Comment: Return type of `getchar` is `int`. You should use proper type.

Comment: what is the contents of: `header2048.h`?

Comment: regarding: `case '\0' :
                printf("NULL character");
                break;`  This takes some 'extra' effort on the part of the user. Suggest removing that `case`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Playing the game");` and several other calls to `printf()`  always end the first parameter with: `\n`  so the text is immediately output to the terminal.  Otherwise, you cannot be sure when that text will be displayed on the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your input loop is not properly handling the "enter" key characters (newlines) that will be in the input stream. To fix this, you can simply add another `case` in your `switch` to handle this (or, really, to ignore it):

```c
        //...
        case '\n': // Newline (= ENTER) character
            printf("NEWLINE character"); // Or just omit this line
            break;
        case '\0':
        //...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fixed it by just taking the first character of user input.